# How to Return a Motor to a specific value

Tags: nxt, motor

I've created an arm robot using Mindstrom NXT that can find an object pick it up and move it to an new and random location. My problem is that I would like for the motor to, at the end of the program, return to the position it started at. The random movement of the arm and how to program it to move back to the starting position is the cause of my confusion. Can anyone give some suggestions or a solution as to what I should do?

Comment: This is fundamentally a variant of [How to remember initial position of a robot and return to it](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2973/56) and [Return a robot to it's start position](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/3134/56)...